# When creating a new middleware, Laravel throws: "Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!"

Tags: php, laravel, crash, xdebug, middleware

I have a fresh Laravel 5.2 install (osx: 10.11, php: 5.6). As I create a new middleware (LocaleMiddleware.php), Laravel crashes with:

> Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

What worries me most is that my app crashes even with the new middleware having an empty/commented out function body!

---

kernel.php

```
...

  /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\LocaleMiddleware::class, //<-- My Middleware
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];
```

---

LocaleMiddleware.php, it crashes my app even when the function body is commented out:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Closure;

class LocaleMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Run the request filter.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        // $language = Session::get('language');
        // //print_r(Session::all());
        // \App::setLocale($language, config('app.locale'));

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Error:

```
in Autoloader.php line 72
at FatalErrorException->__construct() in HandleExceptions.php line 133
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in HandleExceptions.php line 118
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0
at PHPExcel_Autoloader::Load() in ClassLoader.php line 0
at spl_autoload_call() in ClassLoader.php line 29
in ClassLoader.php line 412
at Composer\Autoload\includeFile() in ClassLoader.php line 301
at ClassLoader->loadClass() in Parser.php line 0
at spl_autoload_call() in Parser.php line 45
at Tokenizer->__construct() in Parser.php line 42
at Parser->__construct() in Translator.php line 78
at Translator->__construct() in CssSelectorConverter.php line 36
at CssSelectorConverter->__construct() in CssToInlineStyles.php line 20
at CssToInlineStyles->__construct() in ExcelServiceProvider.php line 111
at ExcelServiceProvider->Maatwebsite\Excel\{closure}() in Container.php line 731
at Container->build() in Container.php line 629
at Container->make() in Application.php line 697
at Application->make() in Container.php line 1178
at Container->offsetGet() in Container.php line 136
at ExcelServiceProvider->Maatwebsite\Excel\{closure}() in Container.php line 731
at Container->build() in Container.php line 629
at Container->make() in Application.php line 697
at Application->make() in Container.php line 1178
at Container->offsetGet() in Container.php line 151
at ExcelServiceProvider->Maatwebsite\Excel\{closure}() in Container.php line 731
at Container->build() in Container.php line 629
at Container->make() in Application.php line 697
at Application->make() in Container.php line 1178
at Container->offsetGet() in Container.php line 186
at ExcelServiceProvider->Maatwebsite\Excel\{closure}() in Container.php line 731
at Container->build() in Container.php line 629
at Container->make() in Application.php line 697
at Application->make() in Container.php line 1178
at Container->offsetGet() in Facade.php line 151
at Facade::resolveFacadeInstance() in Facade.php line 120
at Facade::getFacadeRoot() in Facade.php line 207
at Facade::__callStatic() in SubcategoryController.php line 19
at Excel::load() in SubcategoryController.php line 19
at SubcategoryController->start() in Controller.php line 80
at call_user_func_array:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:80}() in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction() in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call() in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:52}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then() in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack() in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch() in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 140
at Route->run() in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:52}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in LocaleMiddleware.php line 22
at LocaleMiddleware->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then() in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack() in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute() in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch() in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:52}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func:{/Websites/Heuss/lheuss/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:103}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then() in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle() in index.php line 54
at {main}() in index.php line 0
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's an xDebug issue. If you disable that do you still get the error?

Comment: If I disable xdebug, or increase the maximum_level it works. But is it normal for a Laravel app to pass 100 function calls?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I don't use xDebug so I never really come across this error and my apps still run super fast. I would imagine that because of dependencies and the amount of functions the frameworks relies on to run is the reason you hit a limit

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't in your middleware - look at the stack, your app progresses past the middleware and enters the `SubcategoryController`. Looks as though something is going on in a closure in the `ExcelServiceProvider`, so check through that.